# Why are lines showing on my sparkline that are above the max?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-charts

I have this Google sheet, using sparklines to graph a change over time. I want a horizontal line at 2 different points, which cannot be done with a sparkline. So as a workaround, I have 3 different sparklines covering the same data but with different mins and maxes so I can draw a border between them.

But there are 6 parts (encircled in red) where lines are showing on the sparkline where they should not be.

What am I doing wrong?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1paFqu2hWAlpnzc3Ba0uo2kBfy9Inf2X6iWjQTzr_6XE/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are `SPARKLINE` glitches caused by `ymax` when the dataset contains the same consecutive values in the array (rows **10** & **11**, **12** & **13** and **23** & **24**) which are out of bound limited by `ymax` parameter.

an easy fix would be to slightly alter/manipulate duplicates before they hit the `SPARKLINE` output:

**E17** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPARKLINE({A$3:A, 
 IF(COUNTIF(B$3:B, B$3:B)>1, B$3:B+(ROW(B$3:B)*0.0000000001), B$3:B)},
 {"Ymin", 280; "Ymax", 285}))
```

**E19** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPARKLINE({A$3:A, 
 IF(COUNTIF(B$3:B, B$3:B)>1, B$3:B+(ROW(B$3:B)*0.0000000001), B$3:B)},
 {"Ymin", 275; "Ymax", 280}))
```

[image: 0]